# Woocommerce checkouts payment options css loading

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, payment, wordpress-shortcode

I am calling this `woocommerce_checkout_payment()` on a page to display payments options but the payment option's CSS is not being loaded. So this is causing the options to appear disorganized.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding this to the header. `<?php body_class(); ?>`.